# Network application works on Mac OS X, fails to connect on Linux

Tags: c, linux, macos, posix

I wrote a network application on my Mac, which was supposed to run on Linux, because I thought "hey, POSIX is POSIX, it should work", and now I am getting errors connecting to server.

```
TCP_sock = socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
if (TCP_sock < 0) {
  syserr("socket");
}
TCP_open = 1;

memset(&addr_hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
addr_hints.ai_flags = 0;
addr_hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
addr_hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
addr_hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
addr_hints.ai_addrlen = 0;
addr_hints.ai_addr = NULL;
addr_hints.ai_canonname = NULL;
addr_hints.ai_next = NULL;

rc = getaddrinfo(SERVER, PORT, &addr_hints, &addr_result);
if (rc != 0) {
  cleanup();
  fprintf(stderr, "rc=%d\n", rc);
  syserr("getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rc));
  continue;
}

if ((rc = connect(TCP_sock, addr_result->ai_addr, addr_result->ai_addrlen)) != 0) {
  syserr("connect: %s\n", gai_strerror(rc));
  cleanup();
  continue;
}
```

And I am getting an error:

```
ERROR: connect: Bad value for ai_flags
(22; Invalid argument)
```

And just to make things clear:

```
SERVER = "localhost"
PORT = "1234"
```

Of course there is a server running on localhost, on that PORT. What can be wrong?

Comment: Try consulting the relevant Linux man pages https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/

Comment: I did, found nothing relevant.

Comment: Why are you using `AF_UNSPEC' rather than `AF_INET6`? You've already specified `PF_INET6` for *domain*.

Comment: I was using it, but then getaddrinfo returns "getaddrinfo: Name or service not known"

Comment: What are SERVER and PORT?  Can you print addr_result->ai_addr and addr_result->ai_addrlen before calling connect?  Btw, after the connect call gai_strerror needs to be strerror.  It would help if you can post a complete but minimal program according to these guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Both OS X and Linux are not fully compliant with respect to POSIX, and POSIX, like many other standards, still leaves a whole lot of things unspecified. It is better to use a library that wraps all the ugliness if you need cross-platform programming.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this Wikipedia article on getaddrinfo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getaddrinfo), the implementation varies from system to system. Also, [OS X is not fully POSIX compliable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_(operating_system)) (first paragraph). It is certified  as compliant with SUSv3, but that doesn't mean it is fully POSIX compliant, and it does not necessarily implement common features identically to other POSIX-y systems.

So while 'POSIX is POSIX', OS X is not POSIX. You will need to pore through the implementation details of the methods you are calling and figure out how they differ.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems here.

1. gai_strerror only translates error codes returned from getaddrinfo into strings and you are trying to convert the error code returned by connect. Upon failure connect should return -1 and you can check errno and use strerror to convert it to a string. So it most likely has nothing to do with ai_flags.
2. Like the other comment says, you are creating an IPv6 socket and then telling getaddrinfo that you are fine with either IPv4 or IPV6 addresses. Change AF_UNSPEC to AF_INET6 and it should help. So the code that should work better follows (taking into account #1 and #2)

   ```
   TCP_sock = socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
   if (TCP_sock < 0) {
     syserr("socket");
   }
   TCP_open = 1;

   memset(&addr_hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
   addr_hints.ai_flags = 0;
   addr_hints.ai_family = AF_INET6;
   addr_hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
   addr_hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
   addr_hints.ai_addrlen = 0;
   addr_hints.ai_addr = NULL;
   addr_hints.ai_canonname = NULL;
   addr_hints.ai_next = NULL;

   rc = getaddrinfo(SERVER, PORT, &addr_hints, &addr_result);
   if (rc != 0) {
     cleanup();
     fprintf(stderr, "rc=%d\n", rc);
     syserr("getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rc));
     continue;
   }

   if ((rc = connect(TCP_sock, addr_result->ai_addr, addr_result->ai_addrlen)) != 0) {
     syserr("connect: %s\n", strerror(errno));
     cleanup();
     continue;
   }
   ```
3. The usual way to use getaddrinfo is to call it first and then use the information in the addrinfo structs to create the socket and connect it. The Linux man page has a good example with the relevant excerpt here.

   ```
   memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
   hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;    /* Allow IPv4 or IPv6 */
   hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM; /* Datagram socket */
   hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;    /* For wildcard IP address */
   hints.ai_protocol = 0;          /* Any protocol */
   hints.ai_canonname = NULL;
   hints.ai_addr = NULL;
   hints.ai_next = NULL;

   s = getaddrinfo(NULL, argv[1], &hints, &result);
   if (s != 0) {
       fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(s));
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   /* getaddrinfo() returns a list of address structures.
      Try each address until we successfully bind(2).
      If socket(2) (or bind(2)) fails, we (close the socket
      and) try the next address. */

   for (rp = result; rp != NULL; rp = rp->ai_next) {
       sfd = socket(rp->ai_family, rp->ai_socktype,
               rp->ai_protocol);
       if (sfd == -1)
           continue;

      if (bind(sfd, rp->ai_addr, rp->ai_addrlen) == 0)
           break;                  /* Success */

      close(sfd);
   }

   if (rp == NULL) {               /* No address succeeded */
       fprintf(stderr, "Could not bind\n");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   freeaddrinfo(result);           /* No longer needed */
   ```

   The main thing here is that you use the ai_family, ai_socktype and ai_protocol from the addrinfo struct to create the socket that is suitable for use with the sockaddr in the struct.
4. As for why it works on Mac OS X and not Linux I don't know for certain but my hunch is that it has something to do with V4 mapped IPv6 socket capabilities that allow the kernel to use your IPv6 socket to talk with an IPv4 host.